# Tool to to change empty elements to self-closing elements

Tags: formatting, xml

I have a large XML file with many elements like this:

```
<Foo Bar="Baz">
</Foo >
```

I want them all to become like this:

```
<Foo Bar="Baz" />
```

Is there a tool that will do this for me automatically?

Comment: Might be possible using Regular Expressions, but with nested tags and all it can get pretty hairy. A proper XML parser would be a better bet.

Comment: Yes, exactly my thoughts. I could code up a utility myself in something like C#, Java, or Python, but I think that surely such a thing must already exist. And yet, I can not find one :/

Comment: Try [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net) or similar apps that support XPath etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to get `xmlstarlet` to contract elements in the way you described unless you can enumerate the element names to be processed. (This replaces the element value, so you would have to be careful to ensure that it was already empty.)

Example

```
# Create example source
p() { echo >&2; printf "%s\n%s\n" '<Foo Bar="Baz">' '</Foo >'; }

# Show initial output
p

<Foo Bar="Baz">
</Foo >

# Use xmlstarlet to edit the <Foo/> element
p | xmlstarlet edit --update '//Foo' --value ''

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Foo Bar="Baz"/>
```

However, if you don't mind using `sed` to process your XML file (and please note this is generally a *really bad idea*) you might be able to use something like this:

```
sed -Ez 's#<([[:alnum:]]*)( [^>]+)?>\r?\n[[:space:]]*</\1[[:space:]]*>#<\1\2 />#g'
```

Here's what it's doing. First it looks for the pattern between the first pair of `#` characters, `([[:alnum:]]*)( [^>]+)?>\r?\n[[:space:]]*</\1[[:space:]]*>`

- `( ... )` - a grouped expression, each referenced as `\1`, `\2`, etc.
- `[[:alnum:]_]*` - zero or more alphanumeric or underscore characters
- `[^>]+?` - a space followed by anything except `>`, all of which is optional
- `>` - a literal `>` character
- `\r?\n[[:space:]]*` - `optional CR followed by NL and then zero or more spaces

And if found then replaces it with `<\1\2 />`, where `\1` and `\2` are the first and second bracketed expressions.

Example

```
p | sed -Ez 's#<([[:alnum:]]*)( [^>]+)?>\r?\n[[:space:]]*</\1[[:space:]]*>#<\1\2 />#g'

<Foo Bar="Baz" />
```